# to find most frequently occuring element in matrix in R

Tags: r

Is there any function in R to find most frequently occuring element in matrix??I Have a matrix containing image pixels.I want to find which image pixel occur most frequently in the image matrix.I dont want to use the for loops since it would be very time taking to iterate over all the pixels of an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up some test data.

```
> (image = matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    4    4    2    7    2    2    3    8    2     5
 [2,]    7    3    2    6    6    5    7    8    1     3
 [3,]    7    5    7    9    4    9    4    8    2     7
 [4,]    5    3    4    2    1    5    9   10    9     5
 [5,]    9   10    7    2    7    4    9    1    1     9
 [6,]    2    3    5    1    2    8    1    5    9     4
 [7,]    5    4   10    5    9   10    1    6    1    10
 [8,]    6    3    9    7    1    1    9    2    1     7
 [9,]    5    9    4    8    9    9    5   10    5     4
[10,]   10    1    4    7    3    2    3    5    4     5
```

Do it manually.

```
> table(image)
image
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
12 12  8 12 15  4 11  5 14  7
```

Here we can see that the value 5 appeared most often (15 times). To get the same results programmatically:

```
> which.max(table(image))
5 
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Get mode (or majority value) in 1 line of code

using set.seed to generate same random matrix

```
> set.seed(123)
> image = matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
> image
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
  [1,]    3   10    9   10    2    1    7    8    3     2
  [2,]    8    5    7   10    5    5    1    7    7     7
  [3,]    5    7    7    7    5    8    4    8    5     4
  [4,]    9    6   10    8    4    2    3    1    8     7
  [5,]   10    2    7    1    2    6    9    5    2     4
  [6,]    1    9    8    5    2    3    5    3    5     2
  [7,]    6    3    6    8    3    2    9    4   10     8
  [8,]    9    1    6    3    5    8    9    7    9     1
  [9,]    6    4    3    4    3    9    8    4    9     5
 [10,]    5   10    2    3    9    4    5    2    2     6)
```

Mode value of matrix (if tie, its gives minimum tie value)

```
> names(which.max(table(image)))
[1] "5"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any function to do that directly but you can use these functions:

> ```
>  sort(table(as.vector(Matrix))
> ```